# How to design a grid layout as shown in the screenshot in android?

Tags: android, gallery

I am able to query all the images from my device and display them in a linearlayout with a recyclerview but actually i want to display image thumbnails like its shown in android gallery app where the image size is different but they somehow adjust to fit and cover all space

[gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hni7Q.jpg)

plz check the image link as i can't post it in my question because of low reputation

Answer (score 1):

For creating a grid with like your requirement you can get concept from link there are lot of custom grid available on github but this is most common [find it here](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid)

This is example for how to define in xml

```
  <com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:item_margin="8dp"
    app:column_count="@integer/column_count" />
```